# Using .Replace to undo IDs

Tags: vba, excel

first time posting here, so apologies if my format is not correct.
Here's my problem (see below at my attempt to solve):
I have a list of jobs, with IDs of workers assigned to them.
ex. in one sheet "IDsheet"

```
Job       Id

M1       S1 S4

M2       S15

M3       S2

M4       S6          etc
```

In another sheet "Workers" I have

```
Name    ID

Andy    S1

Dave    S2

Hilda   S3

Kerri   S4            etc
```

I am attempting (failing) to write a little bit of VBA for excel so that I can Replace all S1, S2 etc with the correct "Name".

I looked around here and I thought I had found the necessary bit of code, but I have implemented it wrong and my lack of VBA knowledge is probably making me call it incorrectly.

My sub procedure is:

**

```
Sub StaffReplaceAll(code As String, staffid As String)

Dim fnd As String
Dim rplc As String

fnd = code
rplc = staffid

Worksheets("IDsheet").Cells.Replace _
what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True, _
SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

**

and my calling function is:

**

```
Function StaffSub(inval As String, outval As String) As Integer

Call StaffReplaceAll(inval, outval)

End Function
```

**

Where I call "StaffSub" I get #VALUE! error, and the IDsheet is unchanged.

Thanks in advance for any help. BTW: I have also looked at using Vlookup, but I'm not sure that really fits with what I am doing here, also saw 
[This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283972/replacing-excel-data-using-another-spreadsheet) but that just confused me!

Comment: If you have multiple `Id`s for a single `Job`, will there always be a single space between them or are they in separate cells ??

Comment: There's a single space, but I can always split the cells first (if that makes the coding easier)

Comment: Your StaffSub function seems redundant. If you are calling a function from the sheet it cannot change anything other than the cell in which it is placed.

Comment: OK, great - how do I run the *sub* then? I've tried call StaffReplaceAll(B2,A2) within excel and...nothing...

Comment: You can't call StaffReplaceAll from the sheet because it's a sub not a function. You need to call the sub from another sub.

Comment: OK, please point me somewhere - I only started using VBA this week. This issue "can't call StaffReplaceAll" was why I came up with the StaffSub function, but I was told (above) that I don't do it that way...I'm lost!

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that on the *IDsheet*, each `Id` is in its own cell and this block of `Id`s goes from **B2** to at most **Z100**.  The code:

```
Sub david()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, r As Range, v1 As String, v2 As String
    With Sheets("Workers")
        N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To N
            v1 = .Cells(i, "A")
            v2 = .Cells(i, "B")
            For Each r In Sheets("IDsheet").Range("B2:Z100")
                If r.Value = v2 Then r.Value = v1
            Next r
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

With *Workers* like:

[image]

The *IDsheet* is transformed into:

[image]

I am not using **.Replace** because string like *S15* will match both *S1* and *S15*.  I am using individual cells for the `Id`s for similar reasons.

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you! (Great tip on .Replace - I did not know that!). Now, as you can see, I am a complete newbie. How do I call this sub from excel? thanks

Comment: @david  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you so much. That a) works, and b) I understand why - really appreciate your help (the links are great to).  cheers